# Custom Spring Exceptions with bind variables

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to create a custom business exception:

```
public class BusinessException extends RuntimeException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public BusinessException(String msg) {

        super(msg);
    }

    public BusinessException(String msg, Object[] params) {

        //Not sure how to pass params to @ExceptionHandler

        super(msg);
    }

}
```

and use it in my spring mvc rest controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{code}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    String getState(@PathVariable String code) throws Exception {
        String result;
        if (code.equals("KL")) {
            result = "Kerala";
        } else {

            throw new BusinessException("NotAValidStateCode",new Object[]{code});
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I am handling all the businessException using common exception handler:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestErrorHandler {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(RestErrorHandler.class);

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @ExceptionHandler(BusinessException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String handleException(

    Exception ex) {

        Object[] args=null; // Not sure how do I get the args from custom BusinessException

        String message = messageSource.getMessage(ex.getLocalizedMessage(),
                args, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());

        LOGGER.debug("Inside Handle Exception:" + message);

        return message;

    }

}
```

Now my problem is , I want to read the message text from messages property file where some of the keys are expecting run time bind variables e.g.

```
NotAValidStateCode= Not a valid state code ({0})
```

I am not sure how do I pass these arguments to handleException Method of RestErrorHandler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple as you have already done all the "heavy lifting":

```
public class BusinessException extends RuntimeException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final Object[] params;

    public BusinessException(String msg, Object[] params) {
        super(msg);
        this.params = params;
    }

    public Object[] getParams() {
        return params;
    }

}
```

---

```
@ExceptionHandler
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
@ResponseBody
public String handleException(BusinessException ex) {
    String message = messageSource.getMessage(ex.getMessage(),
            ex.getParams(), LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
    LOGGER.debug("Inside Handle Exception:" + message);
    return message;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend encapsulating everything that you need to create the error message in `BusinessException`. You're already passing in `code` as part of the array of params. Either expose that whole array with a `getParams()` method, or (and this is the approach I would take) add a code field  and `getCode()` method to `BusinessException` and add a `code` argument to `BusinessException`'s constructor. You can then update `handleException` to take a `BusinessException` rather than an `Exception` and use `getCode()` when creating the arguments used to create the message.